# Prevent JSON pretty_generate from escaping Unicode

Tags: ruby, json, unicode, utf-8

Is there any way to prevent Ruby's `JSON.pretty_generate()` method from escaping a Unicode character?

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
my_hash = {"my_str" : "\u0423"};
```

Running `JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash)` returns the value as being `\\u0423`.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I cannot repeat this problem. If you are using the hash syntax with a : you must be using ruby 1.9, and all the 1.9.2-3's that I check with perform the correct way as DNNX says here in his answer. You might be using 1.9.1 though (I don't have that version as it never worked well). 1.8.7 doesn't work, and there seems to be no workaround for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question you have a string of 6 unicode characters `"\"`, `"u"`, `"0"`, `"4"`, `"2"`, `"3"` (`my_hash = { "my_str" => '\u0423' }`), not a string consisting of 1 `"У"` character (`"\u0423"`, note double quotes).

According to **[RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), paragraph 2.5**, backslash character in JSON string must be escaped, this is why your get double backslash from `JSON.pretty_generate`.

> Alternatively, there are two-character sequence escape
> representations of some popular characters.  So, for example, a
> string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be
> represented more compactly as "\\".

```
char = unescaped /
       escape (...
           %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C

escape = %x5C              ; \
```

Thus [JSON](http://flori.github.com/json/doc/index.html) ruby gem escape this character internally and there is no way to alter this behavior by parametrizing `JSON` or `JSON.pretty_generate`.

If you are interested in **JSON gem implementation details** - it defines internal mapping hash with explicit mapping of '' char:

```
module JSON
    MAP = {
        ...
        '\\'  =>  '\\\\'
```

I took this code from a *pure ruby variant* of JSON gem `gem install json_pure` (note that there are also *C extension variant* that is distributed by `gem install json`).

**Conclusion:** If you need to unescape backslash after JSON genaration you need to implement it in your application logic, like in the code above:

```
my_hash = { "my_str" => '\u0423' }
# => {"my_str"=>"\\u0423"}

json = JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash)
# => "{\n  \"my_str\": \"\\\\u0423\"\n}"

res = json.gsub "\\\\", "\\"
# => "{\n  \"my_str\": \"\\u0423\"\n}"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, hashes declared using rocket `=>` rather than colon `:`. Also, there is alternative syntax for symbol-keyed hashes since 1.9: `my_hash = {my_str: "\u0423"}`. In this case, `:my_str` would be the key.

Anyway, on my computer `JSON.pretty_generate` works as expected:

```
irb(main):002:0> my_hash = {"my_str" => "\u0423"}
=> {"my_str"=>"У"}
irb(main):003:0> puts JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash)
{
  "my_str": "У"
}
=> nil
```

Ruby 1.9.2p290, (built-in) json 1.4.2.